# Ajax returns 404 when converting directory to application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application that is able to successfully make an ajax call to a controller when hosted under http:// myserver using IIS 7.5, ie

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        serverData = result;
    }
});
```

however if I move this to a sub folder

```
http:// myserver/myapp
```

- right click and "Convert To Application" I get 404's from the ajax call ( the rest of the mvc app loads )

I've attemped variations on the url when I have converted to application each resulting in 404

```
 {virtual-dir-name}/{controller}/{method}
 /{controller}/{method}
 ../{virtual-dir-name}/{controller}/{method}
 ../{method}
```

but I get 404 each variation - is there a practice for using @Url.Action when inside a virtual directory?